# Meaning of version code name on Google Android ROMs?

Tags: rom

While watching [this](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images), I wanted to find out the meaning of version code names like `KRT16M`? Is there any documentation for decoding what it means, or is it just a random hash code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/more-evidence-appears-for-upcoming-android-4-4-3-now-also-spotted-on-a-nexus-7-2013/):

> ... the first letter is the release family (e.g. KitKat), second letter is the branch code (Release or Testing), and the next three characters indicate date code (quarter beginning in Q1 2009, day number within quarter).

Answer (score 0):

I know the `K` stands for KitKat, but not sure what the others mean. You might want to check the [Codenames, Tags, and Build Numbers](http://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html) documentation for more information.

`KRT16M` would refer to `android-4.4_r1`, the `Initial KitKat version, Nexus 5 (hammerhead)`.